# PHP Header() redirect triggers IE9 Quirk mode

Tags: php, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

If I use `header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/test.php' );` to send users to `test.php`. I noticed this in IE9 console:

```
HTML1113: Document mode restart from Quirks to IE9 Standards 
test.php

HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=9') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
test.php
```

This completely mess up my code on `test.php`.

**Question**

I am already using `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` but I am guessing using PHP header() to redirect causes problems with that.

Is there a way to stop IE9 from going into quirks mode when using PHP header() to redirect users?

**Additional Info**

It went to Quirks mode and the back to Standard mode, which seems to break my code on the page.

The user starts in test.php, click submit on a captcha, which POST to verify.php - which has `<?php if (condition){ change some session variables; header(etc); exit();} ?>` right at the beginning.

Comment: I read that as it went *to* Standards Mode. Where is your `header()` code located?

Comment: The opposite, actually. The document mode is going FROM Quirks TO IE9 Standards (when it found the doctype)

Comment: Actual question is, why does it matter to you? Why are you sending a response body anyway? A HTTP redirect shouldn't contain a HTML page.

Comment: It went to Quirks mode and the back to Standard mode, which seems to break my code on the page. The user starts in test.php, click submit on a captcha, which POST to verify.php - which has <?php if (condition){ change some session variables; header(etc); exit();}.

Comment: @mario - when it goes from quirks back to standards, some of my code no longer work on test.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using php to echo a meta refresh redirect instead of the php header appears to have fixed the problem. All the code works, there is no going to quirks mode and back to IE9 mode, and the meta does not get ignored.

**Additional Info**

I spoke to a software/web programmer personally and he doesn't know offhand why this error occurred. However, his opinion is that if meta refresh works instead of php headers, there is no problem using it instead.

Comment: Please comment or post your answer if this is not a good solution.

Comment: it's a perfectly good alternative solution. It doesn't answer the question as to why the problem happened in the first place, but if you've got a working alternative, I guess you don't have to care too much about that now.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this a bit more , and had a thought:

IE9 will jump into quirks mode for any page the doesn't start with a `<!DOCTYPE>`.

The `header(...)` redirect can still have further output after it, which will be seen as a page.

So... if there is any output after the `header()` is sent, and that output does not start with a valid `<!DOCTYPE>`, IE9 could jump into quirks mode.

In PHP, this could happen if the code carries on running after the `header()` call, and something in the subsequent code produces output of some sort.

If this is what is happening, and you don't need the code to keep running after the redirect (which would be unusual) then adding a call to `die();` immediately after the `header()` should fix it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried adding `die()` and also tried `exit()` but both didn't work.

Comment: @Legendre - oh well, it was worth a try. :-) For what it's worth, `die()` and `exit()` are identical in PHP, so if one didn't work, there wouldn't have been any hope for the other (if you look in the PHP source code the `die()` function is a one-liner that simply calls the `exit()` function)